# Merge into (in SQL), but ignore the duplicates

Tags: sql, merge, duplicates, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to merge two tables in snowflake with:

```
On CONCAT(tab1.column1, tab1.column2) = CONCAT(tab1.column1, tab1.column2)
```

The problem here is that there are duplicates. that means rows where column1 and column2 in table2 are identical. the only difference is the column timestamp. Therefore i would like to have two options: either i ignore the duplicate and take only one row (with the biggest timestamp), or distinguish again based on the timestamp. the second would be nicer

But I have no clue how to do it

Example:

```
Table1:

Col1 Col2 Col3 Timestamp
24    10    3  05.05.2022
34    19    2  04.05.2022
24    10    4  06.05.2022


Table2:

Col1 Col2 Col3 
24    10    Null  
34    19    Null
```

What I want to do:

```
MERGE INTO table1 AS dest USING
(SELECT * FROM table2) AS src
ON CONCAT(dest.col1, dest.col2) = CONCAT(src.col1, src.col2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET dest.col3 = src.col3
```

Comment: I only see reference to a single table in the code you've provided...

Answer (score 2):

It feels like you want to update from `TABLE1` too `TABLE2` not the other way around, because as your example is there is no duplicates.

It also feels like you want to use two equi join's on `col1 AND col2` not concat them together:

thus how I see your data, and the words you used, I think you should do this:

```
create or replace table table1(Col1 number, Col2 number, Col3 number, timestamp date);

insert into table1 values
    (24, 10, 3, '2022-05-05'::date),
    (34, 19, 2, '2022-05-04'::date),
    (24, 10, 4, '2022-05-06'::date);

create or replace table table2(Col1 number, Col2 number, Col3 number);

insert into table2 values
    (24, 10 ,Null),  
    (34, 19 ,Null); 


MERGE INTO table2 AS d
USING (
    select * 
    from table1 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by timestamp desc) = 1
) AS s
    ON d.col1 = s.col1 AND  d.col2 = s.col2
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET d.col3 = s.col3;
```

which runs fine:

| number of rows updated |
| --- |
| 2 |

```
select * from table2;
```

shows it's has been updated:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 10 | 4 |
| 34 | 19 | 2 |

but the JOIN being your way work as you have used if that is correct for your application, albeit it feels very wrong to me.

```
MERGE INTO table2 AS d
USING (
    select * 
    from table1 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by timestamp desc) = 1
) AS s
    ON concat(d.col1, d.col2) = concat(s.col1, s.col2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET d.col3 = s.col3;
```

Comment: QUALIFY is one of my favorite SQL functions.  :-)

Comment: Yes, I almost feel I use it more than SELECT. It helps express things so clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col2
                         ORDER BY Timestamp desc) AS rn
    FROM table1
)
UPDATE CTE
SET col3 = (select col3 from table2 where CONCAT(table2.col1,table2.col2) = CONCAT(CTE.col1, CTE.col2))
where CTE.rn =1;
```